# RHEL6 No protocol specified, can't open display

Tags: rhel

I got this when I try to open nco_event in RHEL 6.3

```
[netcool@noi bin64]$ nco_event&
[1] 19962
[netcool@noi bin64]$ No protocol specified
Fatal Error:  /opt/IBM/tivoli/netcool/omnibus/platform/linux2x86/bin64/nco_event: can't open display
```

Any idea to solved that?
I'm still new with linux.

I'm not using SSH, this is my local machine.

Comment: Is this a machine you're logging into with `ssh`? (In which case, does using `ssh -X` help?)

Answer (score 2):

This error means you don't have a X server running. If you are in ssh, you need to forward your X server as stated by Ulrich Schwarz. Also make sure that you have a Xorg server running on your client.

If you are on your local machne, you need to be in a graphical session to run a graphical program.

The following command might help to get the Xorg server in use: `echo $DISPLAY`.